# Native app emulates in iOS but not in Android - Is it the JS?

Tags: php, javascript, android-emulator, jqmobi

I am trying to make a native app using phonegap and jqm.  When I test my app in DW and emulate it with xcode everything seems to work fine.  The problem arises when I try to emulate the app for Android.

The static HTML elements render fine but the dynamic elements do not render in Android.  Here is the HTML that I am trying to render using javascript:

```
// JavaScript Document
//var serviceURL ="http://localhost/UnitedTrackClub/";
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var schedule;

$('#scheduleListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
getScheduleList();
});

function getScheduleList() {
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'get_schedule_hdr.php', function(data) {
    $('#scheduleList li').remove();
    schedule = data.items;
    $.each(schedule, function(index, employee) {
        $('#scheduleList').append('<li><a href="scheduledetail.html?id=' + employee.Duration + '">' +
                '<h4>' + employee.Event_Date + ' ' + employee.Meet_Name + '</h4>' +'</a></li>');

    });
    $('#scheduleList').listview('refresh');

});
}
});
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To me looks like it prints the HTML before to get the data, I found that the native jQuery $.ajax() works better than getJSON in JQMobi so i would do like:

```
$.ajax({
    url      : serviceURL + 'get_schedule_hdr.php',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success  : function(data) {
    $('#scheduleList li').remove();
    schedule = data.items;
    $.each(schedule, function(index, employee) {
    $('#scheduleList').append('<li><a href="scheduledetail.html?id=' + employee.Duration + '">' +
            '<h4>' + employee.Event_Date + ' ' + employee.Meet_Name + '</h4>' +'</a></li>');

});
$('#scheduleList').listview('refresh');
    }

});
```

But I didn't really check your code